# Data Pivot / Unpivot Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot, unpivot

I need some assistance with UnPivot/Pivot/Cross-Apply type operations.

Background: The data are row counts for every table in every database twice in the day: Morning and Evening.

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataCount](
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [TableName] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [RowCount] [bigint] NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [DateForAnalysis] [datetime] NULL,
    [Runtime] [varchar](50) NULL
) 



INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 10, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 10, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableC', 10, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 15, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 15, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 15, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 20, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 20, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableC', 20, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 25, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 25, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableC', 25, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening')
GO
```

Sample Data output required is as per the diagram below - but open to suggestions on how to present the data better.

[image]

Comment: You say you've hit a road block; where is it you got stuck? Can you show us your attempt(s) so far? Were there specific questions you read and didn't understand? What is the block you've hit here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a dynamic pivot.

```
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @ColNames = @ColNames + ',' + DateAndRuntime
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME( CONCAT([Date] , ' ',   [Runtime] )) DateAndRuntime FROM [dbo].[DataCount] ) T

SELECT @ColNames = STUFF( @ColNames ,1,1,'')

DECLARE @PilotSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], CONCAT([Date] , '' '', [Runtime] ) AS [DateAndRuntime] FROM [dbo].[DataCount] ) 
AS  SRC
PIVOT (SUM([RowCount]) FOR [DateAndRuntime] IN ('+@ColNames+')) PVT '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @PilotSql
```

Result:

```
DatabaseName   TableName       2019-10-01 Evening   2019-10-01 Morning   2019-10-02 Evening   2019-10-02 Morning
-------------- --------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
DatabaseA      TableA          15                   10                   25                   20
DatabaseA      TableB          30                   10                   25                   20
DatabaseA      TableC          NULL                 10                   25                   20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple rows with a single values statement

```
INSERT [dbo].[DataCount] ([DatabaseName], [TableName], [RowCount], [Date], [DateForAnalysis], [Runtime]) 
   VALUES (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 10, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 10, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableC', 10, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 15, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 15, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 15, CAST(N'2019-10-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-01 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 20, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 20, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableC', 20, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 09:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Morning'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableA', 25, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableB', 25, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening'),
          (N'DatabaseA', N'TableC', 25, CAST(N'2019-10-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-02 18:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Evening')
GO
```